# SpringBootTest for DAO JUnit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I am attempting the following unit test of a DAO.

I am unable to get the DataSource recognized.

Can I get a tip on how to resolve this?

Details below

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class EntityDaoTest {

    @Autowired 
    protected EntityDao entityDao;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {

    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InternalServerException
    {
        List<Entity> entities = entityDao.list();
        assert(entities.size()==0);
    }
}
```

The relevant aspects of the DAO class are as follows

```
@Repository
public class EntityDao extends GenericDao<Entity>{

    public EntityDao(DataSource dataSource) {/.../}
}
```

My src/test/resources/application.properties file is as follows

```
# Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
```

Trace from running as JUnit test in Eclipse

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityDao': Error creating bean with name 'entityDao' defined in file .../target/classes/hitstpa/dao/EntityDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; 

...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityDao' defined in file [/home/fmason/workspace/hitstpa/target/classes/hitstpa/dao/EntityDao.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. ...`
```

Application structure

-src

--main

---java

----Application.java

----com

----hitstpa

-----controller

-----dao

------EntityDao.java

-----model

---resources

----application.properties

--test

---java

----hitstpa

-----dao

------EntityDaoTestDOTjava

---resources

----applicationDOTproperties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all for integration tests you need an integration Db with some fixed data.

- Now you need to create a configuration class which will create the
  integration test specific dependencies(I have named it as `DbConfig
  .java`)
- Next is add  `@ContextConfiguration` annotation to the integration test
  class and provide `DbConfig.java`, so that when test runs it will
  create the `datasource` dependency and inject it to the container

**Sample Code**

```
    @Configuration
    public class DbConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        //Create the DataSource with integration-DB properties

        return dataSource;
    }
}

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @ContextConfiguration(classes=DbConfig.class)
    public class EntityDaoTest {

    }
```

Comment: These steps got me a bit further as well -- some internal fixes required --- needed to add the tomcat jdbc dependency --- needed to declare zero parameter constructors on all my DAOs.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixIxXRoCr5w -- this helped take me to the next level after I solved these initial problems

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I believe this is not a good unit test. This test requires that a mysql databases exists on localhost.

---

Anyhow, **the errors suggest that the Spring Context isn't loaded correctly**. When using `SpringBootTest`, Spring looks for the configuration using the test's package as root. So, if it's `lower` than your Configuration classes, it won't them.

Take a look at [Spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config):

> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test
>   until it finds a @SpringBootApplication or @SpringBootConfiguration
>   annotated class. As long as you’ve structure your code in a sensible
>   way your main configuration is usually found.

#### Solution:

You can either move your tests to the same level as your SpringBoot Main class or change it to: `@SpringBootTest(classes = YourSpringBootMainClass.class)`

Comment: Agreed it is not a good unit test - just trying to get things set up for now.

Comment: I added the classes attribute to the SpringBootTest annotation and the behaviour didn't change. More about the application structure added above